# jQuery not allowing me to manipulate data in a replaceWith statement

Tags: jquery

When the page loads I have an initial replaceWith that runs the following code:

```
<span id="requestAlert>"
    <span class="font1">wants to be your friend&nbsp;</span>
    <input type="submit" id="acceptRequest" value="Accept" style="width: 60px; 
           height: 28px" class="button1" />&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" id="denyRequest" value="Deny" style="width: 50px; 
           height: 28px" class="button1" />
</span>
```

Then I have the following code that is suppose to manipulate the code above when the page is finished loading:

```
$("#acceptFriend").live('click', function() {
   acceptFriend();
});

function acceptFriend() {
    var targetedUserId = $(document).getUrlParam("id");
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/regUserDash/acceptFriend",
        data: { targetedUserId: targetedUserId },
        json: {acceptFriendSuccess: true},
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.acceptFriendSuccess == true) {
            $("#requestAlert").replaceWith('<span class="font1">You two are noe friends</span>');
          }
        }
    });
}
```

I cannot seem to get the above code to manipulate the initial replaceWith code. I thought maybe .live() would do the trick but apparently not. Any ideas as to why it won't worK? Any solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input has the id `acceptRequest` while your jQuery has the id `acceptFriend`.

Comment: Good catch. I changed it but clicking the Accept button still doesn't so anything

Comment: Okay so I added a test alert to the click function and it works. I guess my ajax is wrong then

Comment: Is the javascript within a PHP file? Otherwise the `<?=base_url()?>` won't work.

Comment: Yeah its in a php file. I've got all that setup in my codeigniter

Comment: Maybe you need quotes around the first `targetedUserId` in your `data:` statement? It's difficult to diagnose this without any more information.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to place targetedUserId outside of the two functions. http://pastebin.com/7JHkY0eu

Comment: Well done. You've got a spelling error at "You two are noe friends" `s/noe/now/`

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in your HTML:

```
<span id="requestAlert>"
```

should be

```
<span id="requestAlert">
```